# How do I check if the property is not readonly so I know I can update it?

Tags: typescript

With the update method I can pass some properties that I want to update the person, but since name is readonly, I get an error.

How do I check if a property is not readonly, then I can update the property?

```
class Person {

  readonly name: string
  age: string
  
  constructor(
    name: string,
    age: string,
  ) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
  }

  update(someProperties: Partial<Person>) {
    let key: keyof typeof someProperties;
    for (key in someProperties) {
      
      // TS2540: Cannot assign to "name" because it is a read-only property.
      // How to creat a check like isWritable(this[key])
      this[key] = someProperties[key]
    }

    return this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, you can't check if a property is read-only while your program is running. But you can still do what you want in a different way.

One way is to make a list of property names that you can change. Then, you can use this list to decide if a property can be changed or not. Here's how you can change your Person class to do this:

```
class Person {
  readonly name: string;
  age: number;

  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  update(someProperties: Partial<Person>) {
    const updatableProperties: (keyof Person)[] = ['age']; // Add other 
updatable properties here

    for (const key in someProperties) {
      if (updatableProperties.includes(key as keyof Person)) {
        // Type assertion to avoid TypeScript errors
        this[key as keyof Person] = someProperties[key] as Person[keyof 
Person];
      }
    }

    return this;
  }
}
```

In TypeScript, you can't figure out if a property can be changed while your program is running. However, you can work around this.

A common trick is to create a list of property names that you're allowed to change. Then, when you use the update method, you first check if the property is in this list before trying to change it. This way, you can avoid trying to change properties that can't be changed.

Just remember to update this list whenever you add new properties that can be changed to your Person class.